# crackling/beeping/distorted audio on my Dell Inspiron after one day running

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, cpu, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. I got it a little less than 2 years ago. For the last year or so I've noticed that when it's on for a little while (a day or two, lately the time is decreasing), audio starts to sound horrible. "Choppy" may be the best description. A crackling sound is very common when listening to music on iTunes or youtube. Sometimes it will also distort the audio and you'll hear a lot of beeping and slow droning. Basically it sounds like a dubstep song, which isn't a great combination with country music if you get my drift. Also it increases with the more high performance tasks I do. When I restart it goes away for probably 10 hours now. It used to be about two days. Are there any ways to fix this problem? My CPU temp is in the high 80's on average and my laptop overheats a lot. If I blow some compressed air in the fans it usually doesn't overheat for a week or so. Thanks.

Specs: CPU: Intel Core i5 480M @ 2.67GHz Arrandale 32nm Technology, RAM: 8.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 531MHz (7-7-7-20), Motherboard: Dell Inc. 0WXY9J (CPU 1)

Comment: use the resource monitor, it is a valuable tool that shows almost everything that is going on with programs. Task manager could show some things, especially if you set it to view IO (read and write bytes). C:\Windows\System32\resmon.exe

Comment: looks like you have DPC issues., Use xperf to trace it: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I'm going to point out the obvious real quick, you will read argumentive blogs back and forth of how long to leave a pc on. It should be shut down daily to let it cool.

Second Windows is terrible about memory leaks and obviously viruses/malware/spyware etc.. The only way to be truly sure its not your hardware going out vs windows being windows. is to reinstall and start fresh. if after a fresh install the problem starts again within the same time limit then the hardware on your machine is going out.

and last. If you run your pc for days on end and its two years old your thermal paste between cpu and heat sink is toast. you need to remove heat sync clean old paste off and replace with HIGH QUALITY paste like artic silver ceramique or the silver stuff. and dont forget it has break in period you will need to shutdown a few times after use to let paste cure properly. Changing just the paste so the cpu cools properly may stop the choppy music.

and also blowing air into the side only pushes dirt and hair further into cpu fan making it clogged and eventually not spin any longer. take laptop apart clean it up. change paste. standard 1 year precedure.